# problems highlighting a word with jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using jquery.textHighlighter.js [see this link](http://mir3z.github.io/jquery.texthighlighter/)

to return text highlighted by the user.

The problem is, if my text is "THIS IS A BEAR.  A BEAR HIBERNATES."  and the user highlights AR in BEAR in the first sentence, they want me highlight the whole word BEAR in the first sentence only.

Is there a way to do this in jQuery?

Comment: Yes, there is. But it's fraught with edge-cases: a sentence is a sequence of characters until a period, so: 'this is a bear.' Unfortunately this is also a single sentence: 'J.D. Salinger is not a bear.' What should be highlighted in that case? And how do you define that, programatically?

Comment: can you describe how i could do this with jQuery?  perhaps i can work around the edge cases